# get safari and chrome opened tabs on mac with Appcelerator

Tags: python, safari, applescript, titanium, appcelerator

I need to read opened tabs URL in Safari, Chrome and Firefox (optionally) and turn them into an array.
I'm using [Titanium Appcelerator to develop a Dektop Application](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest), and it support Python.

It can be also done by calling an AppleScript that return what I'm looking for.
For example this simple AppleScript show what I'm looking for

```
tell application "Safari"
    get URL of every tab of every window
end tell
```

Now how I can call this from Python or JavaScript (I don't know if it's possible with JavaScript) ?

Someone have a great idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can do this via python...

1.(My preference) Install appscript:  `pip install appscript`

```
import appscript
urls = appscript.app('Safari').windows.tabs.URL()
```

2.Shell out to the commandline and call osascript:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
cmd = "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\"' -e 'get URL of every tab of every window' -e 'end tell'"
pipe = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
urls = pipe.readlines()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just embed the AppleScript in a python script like so

```
import os
cmd = """osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\" to get the URL of every tab of every window'"""
def url():
    os.system(cmd)
url()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @stefanodiluca Welcome to StackOverflow! If this solution works, click the checkmark under my answer to let other users know that you have found a solution!

Comment: `subprocess` is now recommended over `os.system`

Comment: The question is also looking for guidance on the AppleScript that will do 'every tab of every window'